# Active Relations: undefined method `city'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.2.4. I know I have set my relations correctly but I'm getting `undefined method "city" for #`

**support.rb:**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**user.rb:**

```
has_many :supports (should the be plural?)
```

**views/users/show.html.erb:**

```
<%= @user.supports.city %>
```

**In my supports table:**

```
t.string :city
t.integer :user_id
```

I have a form for support in which I have filled out the `city` field and I can see in entry with `Support.all` in the rails console so Im sure the value for `:city` is saved in the db.

I have used `rails g scaffold support` for this process where a user can create many supports. Am I missed something?

Comment: Are You sure that user.support is not nil when You call `<%= @user.support.city %>`?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: You can possibly create a user without support. In that case @user.support will be `nil`. Also, by default it is `@user.supports` I guess. Try to create user in the console, then `user.support.create(some attributes)` and then try `user.support.city`

Comment: Forget it :) in case of `has_many` association `@user.support` should be a collection of support objects. `@user.support.first.city` should work. Singular form is a bit confusing :)

Comment: Im still getting `undefined method "city" for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I think that's because You specified a singular form of `support` in `has_many`. It should be plural. I voted up Arsen's answer, it should solve Your problem

Comment: Nothing works. In my rails console I've noticed that `user_id` is not on the `supports` columns but `user_id` shows in the schema. Any ideas?

Comment: I may have issues with my routes resources. I'll sort that out then retry an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `has_many :supports` should be plural
2. `@user.supports` returns all supports but it can return an empty array. So you have to use:

`if support = @user.supports.first
   # use support.city
end`

or

```
<% @user.supports.each do |support| %>
   <h1><%= support.city %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I had issues with my routes and controller. That has been sorted at this works like a breeze. Thank for all the answers. Both worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access associative data, you'll need to understand that pluralized relations (IE `has_many`) will return *collections* of data:

```
#app/models/support.rb
class Support < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user #-> @support.user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :supports #-> @user.supports
end
```

To answer your question about the `:plural`, *no*, you don't need to call it a plural. However, as per Rails convention, it builds the entire relationship (and queries) [off the back of the name](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

> `belongs_to` associations must use the singular term. If you used the
>   pluralized form in the above example for the customer association in
>   the Order model, you would be told that there was an "uninitialized
>   constant Order::Customers". **This is because Rails automatically infers
>   the class name from the association name**. If the association name is
>   wrongly pluralized, then the inferred class will be wrongly pluralized
>   too.

If you wanted to use singular names for your associations with `has_many`, you'll have to define your class etc:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :support, class_name: "Support", foreign_key: "support_id"
end
```

--

When you get your returned data from a `has_many` *collection*, you need to cycle through the data. Since it's a collection (as opposed to a "member" -- single record), you will need to something like the following:

```
<% @user.supports.each do |support| %>
   <%= support.city %>
<% end %>
```